# Returning array from subroutine gives: Compile error: Can't assign to array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

My goal is to return array from subroutine. I've been following [this](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VAA733/YA522820331.htm) tutorial. Here is my code:

```
Function FuncReturnArray() As String
  Dim Films(1 To 5) As String
  Films(1) = "Lord of the Rings"
  Films(2) = "Speed"
  Films(3) = "Star Wars"
  Films(4) = "The Godfather"
  Films(5) = "Pulp Fiction"
  FuncReturnArray = Films
End Function

Sub SubReturnArray()
  Dim Films() As String
  Films = FuncReturnArray()
  MsgBox Films(4)
End Sub
```

`Compile error: Can't assign to array` and editor is pointing to following line: `Films = FuncReturnArray()` what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close - you're really going to kick yourself for this one:

```
Function FuncReturnArray() As String()
  Dim Films(1 To 5) As String
  Films(1) = "Lord of the Rings"
  Films(2) = "Speed"
  Films(3) = "Star Wars"
  Films(4) = "The Godfather"
  Films(5) = "Pulp Fiction"
  FuncReturnArray = Films
End Function

Sub SubReturnArray()
  Dim Films() As String
  Films = FuncReturnArray()
  MsgBox Films(4)
End Sub
```

Notice the top line in the above code - "String" needs to be followed by "()" to indicate that FuncReturnArray is an Array. You may have thought that the brackets after "FuncReturnArray" did this, but actually in that context they are there to reference the fact that there are no arguments being passed to the function.

Comment: Thank you, this worked as expected. Can you please point me to some sources which explains how to debug similar errors? So I do not need to ask those beginner questions again.

Comment: Frankly I was not aware of the ability to do this before - I would have recommended what @ScottHoltzman laid out below. I only discovered this because the link you referenced included the brackets. As far as debugging, calling subs and functions is, in my opinion, a particularly tricky task, in that the syntax matters so much. Note that you appear to have been concentrating on the line *calling* the function, but as you can see, the error was in the function's definition itself. Make sure you look at all elements of an error-ing line - including the elements that call/get called by it.

Answer (score 1):

Make your Function a Variant type.

```
Function FuncReturnArray() As Variant
```

Comment: What is the benefit over String?

Comment: Actually, see Grade 'Eh' Bacon's answer below. Its better than mine. Variant works because its an ambiguous type that will accept everything, but can be **very** costly in terms of memory and resources - so should be avoided as much as possible. In the way you wrote your code, you had the Function returning a flat string value and where trying to assign it to an array.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Everything you wrote was spot on up until this unqualified statement: `[variant]...so should be avoided as much as possible.` That should really be changed to something like, "but at the same time Variants are extremely powerful; but using them well requires understanding quite a bit, so until you do, best to avoid."

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The point is that mastering variants can lead to many important optimizations and we should not paint them as taboo; but rather as advanced.